# PHP Mysql WHILE loop remove the last separator

Tags: php, while-loop

I have this code that get the data from mysql database.

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = $name" );
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql ) ) {
 echo $row[id] . '|';
 echo $row[name] . '|';
 echo $row[add] . ':';
}
OUTPUT : 12|jonathan|philippines:14|John|england:
?>
```

How can I remove the last separator of  `:` using while?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT `id`, `name`, `add` FROM users WHERE name = $name" ); 
$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql, MYSQL_NUM ) ) 
{  
  $data[] = implode('|', $row);
} 
echo implode(':', $data);
```

If you do it like this its a bit more robust, it doens't matter if you change your query right now... It will just output your fields in your wanted format

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = $name" );
$counter = 0;
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql ) ) {

   if ($counter > 0) {
       echo ":";
   }
   echo $row[id] . '|' . $row[name] . '|' . $row[add];
   $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$out = '';
$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = $name" );
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql ) ) {
 $out.=$row[id] . '|';
 $out.=$row[name] . '|';
 $out.=$row[add] . ':';
}
echo substr($out,0,-1);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = $name" );
    $number = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    $i = 1;
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
             echo $row[id] . '|';
             echo $row[name] . '|';
             echo $row[add] ;

       if($i < $number) {
           echo ':';
        }
       $i++;
    }
```